# Trying to configure socket.io from inside feathers

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, feathersjs

Trying to serve feathersjs + socket.io from behind an nginx where it's not mounted at the root. Most of feathersjs can be configured properly but having trouble trying to invoke socket.io's path configuration, i.e. http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#path(v:string):server

nginx config:

```
upstream socket_nodes {
  ip_hash;
  server localhost:19090 ;
}
server {
 ...
 location /spx {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;

    # root   html;
    # index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

and the node.js code:

```
var feathers = require('feathers');
var app = feathers();
app.configure(feathers.rest());
// Configure Socket.io real-time APIs
app.configure(feathers.socketio(function(io){
    io.path('/spx/socket.io');
}));
```

...and yet I'm still getting 404's  when the browser hits  `/spx/socket.io/socket.io.js` .

any ideas?

Comment: It looks like `io.path()` is not doing anything after using `socketio.listen(server)` which is what Feathers uses. I have a fix to pass an options object that can contain the path. Will answer once it lands.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, it looks like `io.path` does not work when calling it after `socketio.listen(server)` which is what happens with Feathers. `v1.3.3` of the [feathers-socketio](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-socketio) module now allows to pass an [options object](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1) which lets you set the path. Although built for Feathers 2 it works just fine with Feathers 1.x (instead of `feathers.socketio`):

```
var feathers = require('feathers');
var socketio = require('feathers-socketio');
var app = feathers();

app.configure(feathers.rest());
// Configure Socket.io real-time APIs
app.configure(socketio({
  path: '/spx/socket.io/'
}, function(io){
  // Do other things here
}));
```